# ajax xhr.upload.addEventListener not working for cross domain call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

I'm trying to create a video uploading progress bar by jquery ajax call from my website to a backend service that is located on same domain, but different port

https://mywebsite.com/upload calling https://mywebsite.com:3000/api/video/upload

Here's my ajax script:

```
$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
  {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
      }
    }, false);

   return xhr;
  },
  url: "https://mywebsite.com:3000/api/video/upload",
  data: dataForm,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  type: 'POST'
});
```

Calling this ajax, my POST request always turned into OPTIONS

```
OPTIONS https://mywebsite:3000/api/video/upload Invalid HTTP status code 404
```

When I remove the xhr function, the ajax script works fine. I was able to upload one video, but without progress listener.

My backend is built on node.js. Thanks ahead for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending GET, POST methods cross domain, a "preflighted" requests is first send by OPTIONS method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests

It looks like you are getting 404 Not Found response. Make sure your request target URI return something such as 200 OK, by allowing OPTIONS method requests to be sent.

Comment: Key point in those docs: "... Or if one or more event listeners are registered on an XMLHttpRequestUpload object used in the request."

Answer (score 2):

I've founded that my server does not support OPTIONS request, so I add this in my node.js file

```
app.options('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.send(200);
});
```

It works well :)

Comment: This resolves the 404, but you'll surely want to set the Access-Control-Allow headers as well so that the browser will allow the subsequent POST request.

Answer (score -1):

uhmmm try something like this: (this is jquery 1.11.x and the php file upload parser is just beside the html file)

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
  function uploadProgressHandler(event)
  {
    $("#loaded_n_total").html("Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total);
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    var progress = Math.round(percent);
    $("#uploadProgressBar").html(progress + " percent na ang progress");
    $("#uploadProgressBar").css("width", progress + "%");
    $("#status").html(progress +"% uploaded... please wait");
  }

  function loadHandler(event)
  {
    $("#status").html(event.target.responseText);
    $("#uploadProgressBar").css("width", "0%");
  }

  function errorHandler(event){
    $("#status").html("Upload Failed");
  }

  function abortHandler(event){
    $("#status").html("Upload Aborted");
  }

  $("#uploadFile").click(function(event)
                         {
                           event.preventDefault();
                           var file = $("#fileUpload")[0].files[0];
                           var formData = new FormData();
                           formData.append("file1", file);

                           $.ajax({url: 'http://testarea.local/UploadWithProgressBar1/file_upload_parser.php',
                                   method: 'POST',
                                   type: 'POST',
                                   data: formData,
                                   contentType: false,
                                   processData: false,
                                   xhr: function()
                                        {
                                          var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                                          xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",
                                                                      uploadProgressHandler,
                                                                      false
                                                                     );
                                          xhr.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
                                          xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                                          xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);

                                          return xhr;
                                        }
                                  }
                                 );
                         }
                        );
</script>
```

Comment: I'm really curious why this works for JQuery and not normal usage of FormData and XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I'm really curios why this was down voted if this actually works.

Comment: Both you and the OP have the `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", ...` line which is one of the things called out in the spec to trigger the preflight OPTIONS check. Without fixing the 404 on the server, your code would surely not work as well. The OPTIONS 404 has to be addressed.

re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests